# What is the replacement for nuxt2 serverinit in nuxt3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I'm trying to use pinia in nuxt3. I need to fetch some data initially when an user visit the page and save it to the pinia store. nuxt2 had a function called nuxtServerinit for that what can I use for nuxt3.

Answer (score 1):

Create `plugins/server-init.server.ts` with content:

```
import { useMainStore } from "../stores/index";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
  if (!process.server)
    return;

  const store = useMainStore();
  // ...
});
```

Copy from [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/5001#discussioncomment-2841138)

Comment: This just don’t work for me on nuxt 3.5.2. I get a error that the function should be inside a setup method